# Can't login on IE and Safari

Tags: login, enterprise-1.13

Customers can not login to Magento using IE or Safari. I have tested with secure and not secure and it doesn't make a difference. Login works fine on Firefox and Chrome.

Attaching login from Safari[image]

[image]

[image]

Here are the PHP and Apache items that Vladimir asked for

Server PHP API would be php-fpm or fastcgi. (I'm assuming that's what he meant anyway.)

Here is the list of installed Apache modules:

```
core_module (static)
mpm_prefork_module (static)
http_module (static)
so_module (static)
cgi_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
authn_file_module (shared)
auth_basic_module (shared)
authz_groupfile_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
include_module (shared)
deflate_module (shared)
log_config_module (shared)
env_module (shared)
mime_magic_module (shared)
expires_module (shared)
headers_module (shared)
unique_id_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
proxy_module (shared)
proxy_connect_module (shared)
proxy_ftp_module (shared)
proxy_http_module (shared)
mime_module (shared)
dav_module (shared)
status_module (shared)
autoindex_module (shared)
info_module (shared)
suexec_module (shared)
vhost_alias_module (shared)
negotiation_module (shared)
dir_module (shared)
actions_module (shared)
userdir_module (shared)
alias_module (shared)
rewrite_module (shared)
fastcgi_module (shared)
ssl_module (shared)
watch_module (shared)
wsgi_module (shared)
```

Comment: Did you tried enabling the iFrame new config? "The options are available in the Admin Panel at System > Configuration > ADVANCED > Admin > Security and are named Allow Magento Backend to run in frame and Allow Magento Frontend to run in frame."

Comment: @mbalparda I am not seeing that option in my Admin. It is Magento 1.13.1.0

Comment: Also I am assuming you meant System->Config->Admin->Security as Advanced has no options other than disabling modules

Comment: I got that from http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes, i think it also applies for the latest EE version.

Comment: @mbalparda Those options are not available until 1.9/1.14

Comment: Can you post the server configuration for PHP (Server API type) and installed Apache extensions?

Comment: @VladimirKerkhoff I edited the post and added the php/apache stuff you wanted

Comment: What does phpinfo() give for Server API? Is PHP running as filter or Handler? Searching for the error in Safari there are some mentions of using it as Filter can cause problems when posting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that live server was unable to execute loginPost action somehow. We changed login page's form action from loginPost to loginpost then it worked fine. (capital P cause issue).

I believe this is a short term answer and I am still unsure why Chrome and Firefox worked fine?

Comment: I'd like to validate that this is the solution to the iOS Safari login issue I have.   What source file(s) need to be modified?

Answer (score 1):

Try these settings in :
System > Config > Web

1. Cookie Lifetime: 86400
2. Cookie Path:
3. Cookie Domain:
4. Use HTTP Only: YES
5. Cookie Restriction Mode: no

Important settings is HTTP Only: YES
Rest of the settings will be default settings. This should work.

I tried all the other options in SO, but they didnt help me, so if anyone else is on same boat maybe try this.